# Hide table row where radio button is selected after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit, cfml

I have table that is contained in form.  The table is built from a CF loop where I have assigned each row ID the NumberID in the sql table.  I have a submit button that performs an jquery ajax submit.  I need to hide the row that was submitted instead of doing a page reload.

```
    <form id="unsortedTable" >
    <input type="submit"   id="makeParentButton" value="Make Parent">
    </span>
    <div class="row-fluid"><p></p>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">


        <tbody>
      <cfloop query="nonAffiliated">

          <tr id="#NumberID#">
            <td><input type="radio"  name="NumberID" value="#NumberID#"></td>
          </tr>
      </cfloop>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Then I have the JavaScript that triggers when the submit is performed.

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#unsortedTable").submit(sendForm);

    });

    function sendForm() {
       var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $.post('handlers/formHandler.cfm',
        $("#unsortedTable").serialize(),function(data,status){
        $("#unsortedTable")[0].reset();

        row.hide(); //This is just a guess
    });
    return false


 }
```

Everything works except I can't get that submitted row to hide().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the form is within the table row you are trying to hide, `$(this).closest('tr')` will not find the row. You probably thought `$(this)` does refer to the button clicked, but you are using a subit handler on the form, not a click handler on the button.

You might want to find the row a different way, either by `id` or by finding the button first:

```
$('#rowId').hide();
```

or

```
$('#buttonId').closest('tr').hide();
```

EDIT:

After re-reading your question more carefully, I realized that you don't want the submit button to be hidden, but the radio button.  For that you could do something like this:

```
$(this).find('input:radio:checked').closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the ID until the page is loaded.  CF provides them. Maybe write an ajax function that gets the ID that was submitted?

Comment: I just realized that I misread your original question.  So I updated my answer above.

Comment: THANK YOU! THAT SAVED ME A LOT OF WORK LOL